# Missing loop variable in if clause?

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I have a bash script that looks basically like this:

```
for f in "mydirectory"/*; do
    someprogram "$f"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "someprogram had an error on $f"
    fi
done
```

It runs fine, but if "someprogram" returns an error, I get the following message:

```
someprogram had an error on
```

For some reason the loop variable "f" has been forgotten inside the if statement.  Is this correct?  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Add your shebang and how do you start your script?

Comment: No, this does not normally happen. Consider making a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).